# Is it possible to use true Blinn-Phong lighting on Unity Android/IOS?

Tags: unity, shaders, mobile

I've noticed that the Unity's Legacy Shaders/Specular shader does not work on mobiles due to the lighting model being incompatible. I then tried using the Mobile/Bumped Specular shader, but this shader does not support non-directional lights. So I tweaked the mobile specular shader to remove the noforwardadd argument, but I noticed that specular highlights are improperly positioned for non-directional lights, even after removing the halfasview/interpolateview argument. Does Unity even support non-directional specular highlights on mobile devices?